# Using web app plugin from Mobile app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I am building a mobile app that all it does it call to web app which will be the app itself. 
I am using ionic, cordova, angular ...

The mobile app is very simple and all it has is:

```
<content src="http://1.1.1.1:8080/testWeb/www/index.html"/>
```

In the web app I am trying to do a simple bar code scan. 
When emulate the app on android I get to the web app with the scan button but when I click it I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
at Object.scan (ng-cordova.min.js:7)
at Scope.$scope.scanBarcode (testControllers.js:8)
at $parseFunctionCall (ionic.bundle.js:21044)
at ionic.bundle.js:53458
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:23100)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23199)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:53457)
at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:11713)
at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2863)
at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2852)
```

all I need is to do a bar code scan but I want it to be done from the web app and not the mobile app.

Any suggestions? is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Cordova and it's plugins are only available from the mobile app not the web app...

Comment: So, If It can't be done this way? can I call the mobile app cordova.js from the web app?